# Call classes in Java?

Tags: java, vba

I am coming from VBA and don't really know if the following thing works:

I want to call few classes / functions in Java from a let's say "Master Class".

For example I would do something like this in VBA:

```
Sub MasterClass()

Call ExampleClass1
Call ExampleClass2
Call ExampleClass3
Call ExampleClass4

End Sub
```

or for a command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call MasterClass

End Sub
```

When calling this "MasterClass", it would call / execute all the other classes in order.

Is there a similar way of doing this in Java?

Comment: "Call a class" makes no sense in Java context. You can call methods of class instances, but not just "call classes" themself.

Comment: VBA is events driven programming while Java is Object oriented. Those are different concepts. You should start with learning the basics Java concepts.

Comment: Call a class doesn't make sense in VBA either.

Comment: `sub routine| procedure` != class. You are  confusing `subs` with `class` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Java works very similar way, but class call is not possible. You can crate instance of a class and it will work inside the constructor. For example :

```
public class ExampleClass1 {
    public ExampleClass1() {
        System.out.println("It is a ExampleClass1 ");
    }
// methods
}

public class ExampleClass2 {
    public ExampleClass2() {
        System.out.println("It is a ExampleClass2 ");
    }
// Methods 
}
public class Master {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new ExampleClass1();
        new ExampleClass2();
    }

}
```

Output:

```
It is an ExampleClass1 
It is an ExampleClass2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a class in Java. However, you can call methods that belong to a class. Classes are often used to create objects.

So for example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        //print test
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Now that we have this class, we can construct an object from it like this:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
```

We can also call the method we defined in that class with our new object. (if it is a static method we do not need to construct an object to call it).

```
myObject.myMethod();
```

output: test

[Object oriented programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-oriented-programming-oops-concept-in-java/) can be confusing at first but I recommend you research that if you want to start using Java

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me tremendously to understand it better.

Comment: @OgaOverflow Glad I could help!